# UITableView inside UiViewController not align center

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, xcode8

I want to put an UiTableView inside an UiViewController because i'll customize the header of the ViewController and i'm having some problems on aligning the tableview to the center of the view.

[image]

[image]

I've set some constraints for the Title and for the TableView.

For the Title, I've set **Vertical Spacing to Top Layout Guide** and in the Align section **Center Horizontally to 0**.

For the TableView, I've set **Vertical Spacing to the Title** and also set some constraints in Pin section like photos below

[image]

[image]

[image]

So when I go to preview the ViewController in different sizes, the Switch element won't show and as you can see, the Table View Prototype Content is not in the center.

[image]

Did anyone had the problem before?

I'll appreciate any help.

Thanks!

**UPDATED**

It was really a problem with Xcode and after running the APP in the simulator, the switch was showed like image below:

[image]

Comment: share a screen shot of view hierarchy of view controller

Comment: Run the app and show the screenshot

Comment: i think its xcode issue as @thewarri0r9 says run in device & check it

Comment: Krunal, I posted the screen shot like you asked.

Comment: Thanks @thewarri0r9 it was really a xcode rendering problem.

Comment: Thanks also @DSDharma for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the `Equal Widths` constraints.

Hold Right button and connect tableView to the Main View and select `Equal Widths`.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I've set and nothing changed.

Comment: Yes. I'll just implement the method to get my json data from the server and I'll post the screenshot.